# Is this sentence correct? It was he who had committed the thief

Tags: grammar

I'm confused need help please thanks. Any grammar police on here to assist me with this concern.

Comment: You probably mean [*It was he who had committed the **theft***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22who+committed+the+theft%22) (stole something). Unless "he" is a criminal psychologist or magistrate, [sectioning](https://www.mind.org.uk/information-support/legal-rights/sectioning/about-sectioning/) or sentencing the thief for treatment or punishment. What do you want your sentence to mean, and what are you unsure about?

Comment: It's awkward for me this sentence it's sound weird the part he who had it doesn't sound natural but accordingly to internet is correct  the wrong one is it was he had committed the theft.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. What *exactly* is it about the sentence that makes you question its grammaticality? Only when you help us understand your current thinking can we possibly help you improve it.

Comment: Perhaps it would help you if you compared the sentence to one like “He needn’t have apologized because it was I who had made the error.”

Comment: There are no grammar police.  There are no laws to be enforced, only patterns to copy.  You haven't told us what "this concern" is.  It is something to do with a sentence, but your question is unclear and so I've voted to close, and so block further answers.  You can edit to explain what your concern is (and fix an spelling mistakes you might have made)

Comment: Thanks for nothing.

Comment: @NaioB There is no need to be rude to those trying to find out what your problem is. Although your sentence is grammatically correct, as pointed out by FumbleFingers, it's probably not what you meant and you may have made a spelling mistake. There is a lot of guidance on how to ask good questions so why not read https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask to start with?

Answer (score 1):

As @FumbleFingers commented, likely you are asking about

> It was he who had committed the **theft**.

If *he* is a criminal psychologist or magistrate, *thief* would be right.

From your further comments, your doubt is in fact on the omission of the relative pronoun *who*.

Relative pronouns that are subjects of relative clauses cannot be omitted, as in your example.  It would be ungrammatical to say

> *It was he had committed the theft.